# split(/\s+/).pop() - what does it do?

Tags: javascript, regex, split

Could you translate this expression to words?

```
split(/\s+/).pop()
```

It is in javascript and uses regex to split a string, but what are the principles?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

That line of code will split a string on white space to create an array of words, and then return the last word.

Presumably you have seen this used on a string of some kind, e.g.:

```
var someString = "Hello, how are you today?";
var lastWord = someString.split(/\s+/).pop();
```

In which case `lastWord` would be `"today?"`.

If you did that one step at a time:

```
var someString = "Hello, how are you today?";
var words = someString.split(/\s+/);
```

Now `words` is the array: `["Hello,", "how", "are", "you", "today?"]`

Then:

```
var lastWord = words.pop();
```

Now `lastWord` is the last item from the array, i.e., `"today?"`.

The [`.pop()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) also actually removes the last item from the array (and returns it), so in my second example that would change `words` so that it would be `["Hello,", "how", "are", "you"]`.

If you do it all in one line as in my first example then you don't ever actually keep a reference to the array, you just keep the last item returned by `.pop()`.

MDN has [more information about `.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).

Another way to get the last word from a string is as follows:

```
var lastWord = someString.substr( someString.lastIndexOf(" ") + 1 );
```

Answer (score 3):

### TLDR:

1)the split part creates an array based on the regex /\s+/ (which means separate by whitespace)

2) the pop part returns the last element of the array

could be rewritten as

```
var array = "one two three four five".split(/\s+/);
var lastMemberOfArray = array.pop()
```

I often use split(".").pop() to get file extension

```
var html = "holidays-and-parties/photos/a-pioneer-halloween.html"
var ext = html.split(".").pop(); // ext now holds 'html'
```